# How to identify element for notifications that disappear within few seconds?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've a test case where after creation of an item, notification is shown, but that notification disappear s within 2-3 seconds.

I want to identify the element for that notification, but when I try to inspect element for that in firebug, it's HTML snippet disappears very quickly since notification itself disappears. Hence I couldn't identify element for it and finding it very difficult to automate.

Can anyone suggest how to deal with such situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say "I've a test case", I'm thinking you are testing an application of yours. The plainest way to get around your problem is to know your application. Even if a third-party library is providing the notification code, you can read the doc to see if you can increase the delay or you can read the source code to figure out how it creates the element and where.

If the above fails, then if you can get together a sequence of operations in Selenium that triggers a notification, you should be able to get a serialization of `body` quickly enough that you can then examine at your leisure. Using Selenium for Python, it would go:

```
print driver.execute_script("return document.body.outerHTML;")
```

I would run the code above with redirection to save the output of the `print` statement to a file that I'd then examine at my leisure. You could make it narrower if you wish by getting the `outerHTML` of a descendant of `body`. I like to have a good bit of context so that I know where exactly the element is being created. I've used libraries and configurations that create such notifications as children of `body`, and some that put them as children of other elements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the previous page before the notification
2. Press "Ctrl+Shift+c", Navigate to "sources" tab
3. Do the manual step to generate the notification, which is going to hide in few seconds
4. Press "F8". Page load scripts will be paused
5. Then inspect the element as usual and fetch the xpath at your convenience

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below **JAVA code** to **wait for 20 seconds till any element with text 'your notification' appears in the page**:

```
try{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Your notification here')]")));
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Error while waiting for the notification to appear: "+ e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: OPs problem is that he cannot locate the element because it disappears too quickly for him to indentify the xpath/cssSelector. Making Selenium wait will not change the behaviour of the application to help him

Comment: That's the very reason I have used the above code. It will wait till the element having the text , i.e., "Notification message" appears, rather than waiting for the Notification than assert the text in it.. Hope you get it.. :)

Comment: Steve Crawford is right. This does not do what the OP asked. Additionally, a test like this one that fails does not provide much information regarding what the failure was exactly. Is it that the notification never came up? Or that the notification did come up but with an unexpected message? We don't know. If the OP finds how the notification structurally appears in the DOM, the OP can then write a test that will distinguish these two failure modes. (And yes, I've had both failures happen while testing real applications.)

Comment: That's very correct @Louis. What I have provided above, may not be an apt solution, but sure is another way to overcome the problem what OP is facing (Indirectly), as he/she is not able to inspect the notification.